# Get Decibels data from recorded audio in iOS and Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to get decibels values from a recorded audio sample in order to make a wave chart and process its peaks.
At the moment I'm using `AVAudioRecorder` to record an audio file and access its DB values by using `[recorder averagePowerForChannel:0]`, called by a timer, however I am facing a limitation. Since I need to be the most precise as possible I have set the timer to repeating at 0.001s, however calling `[recorder averagePowerForChannel:0]` at each tick outputs the same value multiple times. It seems like the recorder is not able to update the values below 0.2s.
How could I overcome this limitation?

This is the recorder setting:

```
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44000.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                  nil];
```

Then I setup the recorder

```
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
    [recorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [recorder record];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001f target:self selector: @selector(cllBack:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

And in cllBack I call

```
[recorder updateMeters];
[recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you need to do this realtime or offline? AVAudioRecorder is not meant for this, those values are more for recording UI updates, not for processing. You could try going lower level, e.g. using AVAudioEngine. Moreover, such NSTimer won't be precise, as it runs on a contended main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using AVAudioEngine by installing a tap on bus and analyzing the data.